# Why the props in react become the next argument in function return a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, closures

When we pass a function in a function  as an argument, the function that we pass in it has own parameter, but why the parameter become an argument of next returning function ?

```
function combineStyles(...style){
   return function CombineStyles(theme){}
}
```

```
const s1 = theme => ({
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: '#fff',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
});
```

```
const combinedStyles = combineStyles(s1);

export default withStyles(combinedStyles)(MyComponent);
```

```
// While i am log it, i got same result 

const s1 =  theme => console.log(theme);

// Same as :

function combineStyles(...style){
   return function CombineStyles(theme){ console.log (theme) }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get what you're asking!?

Comment: when i pass s1 to combineStyles, then the parameter of s1 that is 'theme' become an argument of the next function that is 'CombineStyles', why work like that ?